# Caeteris paribus

Tags: philosophy-terms, terminology, logic

*Caeteris paribus* means "all else being equal" yet, terminologically, also stands in for "all else unchanged". I'm interested in knowing actually how to say "all else unchanged" in a way that bears resemblance to *caeteris paribus*.

Answer (score 8):

The third part of Descartes's *Principia Philosophiae* (pg. 78 of [this edition](https://books.google.com/books?id=rr2M1H7FDYoC&pg=RA2-PA78)) contains a more literal translation of "all things unchanged":

> Si autem **caeteris immutatis**, contingat ut minuatur illa vis...

Note that I only found 150 G-hits for this phrase: I highly recommend the (almost) exactly equivalent and far more prevalent *ceteris paribus*. If you are writing in English, I would especially discourage using *caeteris immutatis*.

Also, note that *ceteris* (without an *a*) is a much more common spelling.